# Запятые и орфография

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Где поставить запятую?

> Привычки которые человек приобрел в школьные годы и от которых не смог избавиться иногда вредят ему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Привычки, которые человек приобрел в школьные годы и от которых не смог избавиться, иногда вредят ему.**

Однородное подчинение: придаточные предложения являются однотипными и относятся к одному и тому же члену главного предложения или ко всему главному предложению в целом. Например: *Она глядела, как сизые кольца дыма от сигары Азазелло уплывали в камин и как кот ловит их на конец шпаги (Булгаков).*